# Read data from excel in Selenium Webdriver with c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am working with selenium webdriver c#. I need to read data from excel.

Code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;



namespace UIL
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UIL_Login : UtilityHelper
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
        Excel.Application loginapp;
        Excel.Workbook loginworkbook;
        Excel._Worksheet loginworksheet;
        Excel.Range loginrange;

        public UIL_Login()
        {
            loginapp = new Excel.Application();
            loginworkbook = loginapp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\\MyProjects\\Selenium_C#\\SeleniumProjects\\UIL\\UIL\\Resources\\login.xls");
            //loginworksheet = loginworkbook.Sheets[1];
            loginworksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)loginworkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            loginrange = loginworksheet.UsedRange;
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\\MyProjects\\Selenium_C#\\Selenium\\chromedriver");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.168.0.35:92");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        /*Login without username*/
        [TestMethod]
        public void loginWithoutUsername()
        {
            try
            {
                int emptyUsernameRowNumber = 1;
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000);
                IWebElement username = webElement(driver, Constants.VAR_EMAIL);
                username.Clear();
                //username.SendKeys("amrutha.u@teamta.in");
                username.SendKeys(loginrange.Cells[emptyUsernameRowNumber][1]);
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000);
                IWebElement password = webElement(driver, Constants.VAR_PASSWORD);
                password.Clear();
                // password.SendKeys("UIL@123#");
                password.SendKeys(loginrange.Cells[emptyUsernameRowNumber][2]);
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000);
                IWebElement signinButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='mainDiv']/div[4]/div/div/form/a/button"));
                signinButton.Click();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

But i am getting the following exception:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best
>   overloaded method match for
>   'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement.SendKeys(string)' has some invalid
>   arguments    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , IWebElement ,
>   Object )    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

Can anybody help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you're passing a parameter of `Cells` type to the `SendKeys()` method, when it's expecting a `string`.

Try `loginrange.Cells[emptyUsernameRowNumber][1].Value2.ToString()`

Note:
I'm assuming that the you have the data you need in your cell.

Comment: Tried loginrange.Cells[emptyUsernameRowNumber][1].ToString(), but the same exception

Comment: Convert.ToString(loginrange.Cells[emptyUsernameRowNumber][1].ToString()) worked for me, but the value i am getting is System._ComObject.

Comment: Updated the answer. I tried it out and it should work now.